# ASP.NET Master Page and User Content Forms

Tags: asp.net, forms, master-pages

Is there a good way to enable forms that come out of user content (CMS) that is displayed inside the form runat="server" tag? All sorts of services provide forms for users to paste into their website, which break if the content ends up inside a .net form. It seems to me that there must be a good way around this, but I can't seem to find any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The one solution I've found is to put them in an `IFRAME`. So instead of embedding your form inside the page:

```
<FORM action="http://www.example.com/target.html">
  .. form content
</FORM>
```

create a new ASPX file like this:

```
<FORM action="http://www.example.com/target.html" target="_top">
  .. form content
</FORM>
```

Then in your original page, you'll refer to it via an `IFRAME`:

```
<IFRAME src='myform.aspx'></IFRAME>
```

Some things you'll need to do:

- Make sure that you do not include any `<FORM runat="server">` inside the new ASPX file.
- Adjust the size of the IFRAME and the ASPX file to be exactly the same
- For the `FORM` in the new ASPX files, you probably want to set `target='_top'` to ensure when a user fills in the form, the result is in the main window rather than inside the `IFRAME`.